# MySQL returns same result multiple times even with Distinct

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, distinct

Here is `sql`

```
        SELECT DISTINCT
            t1.`name` team1_name,
            t1.id team1_id,
            t2.id team2_id,
            t2.`name` team2_name,
            sc.`name_en` sportCatname,
            c.title championshipTitle,
            e.date eventDate,
            e.id eventId,
            e.title,
        FROM
            `Event` e,
            `SportCategory` sc,
            `Championship` c,
            `Team` t1,
            `Team` t2
        WHERE
            e.top = 1
        AND t1.id = e.team1ID
        AND t2.id = e.team2ID
AND sc.id = c.sportCategoryID
```

Tried with JOIN also. No way. It returns corrects rows but, in result set I have same row 2 times. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should really prefer using explicit `JOIN`s over the outdated implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relationship for `SportCategory` and  `Championship` in the where clause. This is the reason for having duplicate results.

You should provide the relationship in the `where` clause.

Comment: `AND sc.id = c.sportCategoryID` added this line. Now every result 2 times in resultset. Yes it reduced result rows. But not to 1 time

Comment: @heron: you have to add anothr one. one of the table should be either `SportCategory` or `Championship` and another one should be from rest of the 3 tables.

Comment: That's a *very* good example why the outdated implicit joins in the `where` clause should be avoided. When using explicit `JOIN` syntax, you can't accidently forget a join and generate a cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if any column has a special characters that are not in other rows?